# How to get spark-submit hive context running properly with tez and yarn?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, tez

I've been trying to get spark-submit to work with  org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext, but I keep coming out with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tez/dag/api/SessionNotRunning. Here is the code, which breaks on the last line:

```
val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

This is on Hortonworks 2.3.4, with spark 1.5.2, hive 1.2.1, hadoop 2.7.1, and tez 0.7.0. I'm using maven for all dependencies except data nucleus, I have hive-site.xml and tez-site.xml in the --files argument of spark-submit. Here is the tez related excerpt from my pom:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tez</groupId>
        <artifactId>tez-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tez.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tez</groupId>
        <artifactId>tez-dag</artifactId>
        <version>${tez.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tez</groupId>
        <artifactId>tez-common</artifactId>
        <version>${tez.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

This code works properly in spark shell. Any advice?

Comment: I couldn't understand, since you are using Spark why to use tez? Spark could do all the job alone even when using HiveContext.

Comment: @user1314742, 
I'm not specifically trying to use tez. The exection engine, from hive-site.xml is tez on our cluster. I'm adding the dependencies to try to get rid of the error.

Comment: So put new hive-site.xml into your spark conf directory and try to remove tez and try again..  that should resolve the problem

Comment: @user1314742, that worked, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Good, I ll add more choices to do the job on your answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @user1314742's advice, I removed everything tez related from hive-site.xml. I included it in the --files argument to spark-submit, so as not to change my actual hive configs.

> So put new hive-site.xml into your spark conf directory and try to remove tez and try again.. that should resolve the problem